# Aggregate multiple actor responses in a particular response format?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I want to combine two responses from different actors into one map, technically I want to have a map response  convert into json object which looks like below

```
{ configurations : <config>,
  members : [<List of Members>]
}
```

The response body should look like above, how can I achieve that in the json format or even in the form of a map from the code below with the above keys. How can I combine two responses in such a way. I don't think my "for" logic below captures it correctly. How can I introduce key names in the code below?

```
def receive = MetricsReceive {
 case MetricsRequest =>
  val config = config ? ConfigMetricsRequest mapTo[ConfigMetrics]
  val members = (members ? MembersRequest mapTo[Members])
  for {
    c <- config 
    m <- members
  } yield fun(c, m)
}
```

Comment: It depends on what `fun` does, so hard to comment any further.

Comment: Create a case class instead of a map, for example `case class MetricsResponse(configurations: ConfigMetrics, members: Members)`. Then convert this instance of your case class to JSON with any JSON library. Most JSON libraries provide functionality to automatically convert case classes to an appropriate JSON object with the expected keys.